# Running multiple instances of the same program in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-instances

I have some specialist legacy software which is no longer supported/maintained, which I'd like to get running in two or more instances so that I can work more easily with two windows side by side. The software is a coding environment to produce machine code for a CNC router.

Here's what I've worked out so far:

If I just try shift-clicking the taskbar to open a new instance, nothing happens. Similarly if I double-click the .exe then nothing happens. Nothing shows up on the screen and a second instance won't run.

I have two slightly different versions of the software: 01.14.026.1006 and 01.14.026.1012 (so quite a minor revision between the two). Only one of these works correctly for what I need, however I know that I am able to run a copy of one version and a copy of another version simultaneously. I'm assuming that this tells us something about how the program determines if a copy is already running, though I'm not knowledgeable enough to know what.

Changing the name of the .exe file doesn't change anything, nor does copying the install files to a new location and running from there, or going through another install process from the CD.

I've tried "Run as different user" and it's the same - nothing happens when trying to run.

I *have* managed to get two instances running through Sandboxie (https://www.sandboxie.com/) but I'd like to understand the process of figuring out how the software is stopping multiple instances from being run and getting around it without virtualisation. I've looked at the other questions already on SuperUser and none of the answers seem to work. One of them mentioned mutexes and using Process Explorer to see what's going on, but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: "I'd like to understand the process of figuring out how the software is stopping multiple instances" - In programming they use a mutex or [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  It is basically a lock on a thread.  To make it simple, a mutex is a locked door to a thread, and only one process at a time can open the door.  Once a thread opens the door they lock it.  Sandboxie works because of how it treats every process, it reproduces every Win32 call, and isolates the program. So a call to the Win32 mutex class is commnicating with Sandboxie directly not Windows.

Comment: In addition to what Ramhound said I found some apps that use different methods. Like checking for a window title and process and quit if it already exist. Mostly simple apps tho